# react-native when call MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() is always false

Tags: ios, react-native, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an IPAD with mail configured but when i check this function MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() is always return false

i call objective c from react-native

when i call mail without this check the application crash

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: I am getting the same with the react-native-share library.